# How to match <div> heights across two stacks of <div>'s to create pseudo table with just CSS?

Tags: css

I have two "columns" of stacked `<div>`s that are side by side, and there are an equal number of `<div>`s in each column.  Each `div` is equivalent to a table row.  However, since it's not a true table, if one `div` in the left stack/column has more lines of content than its corresponding `div` in the right column the "rows" will not be aligned.  I am wondering how I could set the height of the `div`s to match to each other.

[Here is a picture of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWlNM.png) You can see where the row splits in the third row.

This is set up on a Mediawiki farm and due to some constraints from that and from the extensions used, I cannot access the html here or create a real table here, and am hoping for a CSS-only solution.  I've looked at using `calc()` and variables in a stylesheet, as well as `display:table` but I can't wrap my head around it.

```html
<!--The Header -->
<section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color pi-collapse" data-item-name="itemAttributes">
  <h2 class="pi-item pi-header pi-secondary-font pi-item-spacing pi-secondary-background">Attributes</h2>

<!--The first column -->

  <section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color" data-item-name="itemAttributeNames">
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability1name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Darkvision</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability2name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Thick Skin</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability3name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Invulnerability</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability4name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Shapeshift</div>
    </div>
  </section>

<!--The second column-->

  <section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color" data-item-name="itemAttributesDesc">
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability1">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">The helm allows the wearer to see in dim light.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability2">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Grants immunity to poison.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability3">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Grants immunity to wounds. This is a pretty big deal. Like, super over powered. Someone should write to the editor. Or call them. Call right now so we can get some clarification on what the heck is going on here. We need answers. #wtf</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability4">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">The helm gives the wearer the ability to take any form.</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

For current CSS I just have the two sections set to 50% width and float left (along with other non-relevant things).

Comment: Using jQuery or JS will be required. Because set the 2 section next to each other will not a problem. But set height of child from a section to another will not be possible without js.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with your code setup running some ridiculous js calculations and asserting divs heights.

Instead, I'd advocate for another code setup using css flex setup.

See [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.prop { display:flex; }
.key { flex-shrink:0; flex-grow:0; flex-basis:25%; }
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <h2> Attributes </h2>

  <section class="content">
    <div class="prop">
      <div class="key"> Darkvision </div>
      <div class="val"> The helm allows the wearer to see in dim light. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prop">
      <div class="key"> Thick Skin </div>
      <div class="val"> Grants immunity to poison. </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prop">
      <div class="key"> Invulnerability </div>
      <div class="val"> Grants immunity to wounds. This is a pretty big deal. Like, super over powered. Someone should write to the editor. Or call them. Call right now so we can get some clarification on what the heck is going on here. We need answers. #wtf </div>
    </div>
    <div class="prop">
      <div class="key"> Shapeshift </div>
      <div class="val"> The helm gives the wearer the ability to take any form. </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

**From your HTML code**, without JavaScript ,  grid is also a possibility:

- a example setting each rows to the same height ....*some will seem very empty unfortunately unless short content can be aligned to center*

```css
body>section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

body>section>h2 {
  grid-column: 1/ span 2;
}

body>section>section {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;/* here is the handy part */
  border: solid 1px;
}

section>div {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 0.15em
}


/* only for the demo and a touch of flex ;)  */

section>section>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

section>section:first-of-type>div {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!--The Header -->
<section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color pi-collapse" data-item-name="itemAttributes">
  <h2 class="pi-item pi-header pi-secondary-font pi-item-spacing pi-secondary-background">Attributes</h2>

  <!--The first column -->

  <section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color" data-item-name="itemAttributeNames">
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability1name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Darkvision</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability2name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Thick Skin</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability3name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Invulnerability</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability4name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Shapeshift</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--The second column-->

  <section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color" data-item-name="itemAttributesDesc">
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability1">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">The helm allows the wearer to see in dim light.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability2">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Grants immunity to poison.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability3">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Grants immunity to wounds. This is a pretty big deal. Like, super over powered. Someone should write to the editor. Or call them. Call right now so we can get some clarification on what the heck is going on here. We need answers. #wtf</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability4">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">The helm gives the wearer the ability to take any form.</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

---

- `use display:contents` to virtualy make div direct children of the parent section which has a grid layout set . rows will match to their max-content ... but it is a workaround/trick  that not every browser understands :

```css
body>section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  width: 800px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

body>section>h2 {
  grid-column: 1/ span 2;
}

body>section>section {
  display: contents
}

section>div {
  border: solid;
}

h2+section>div {
  grid-column: 1;
}

h2+section+section>div {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<!--The Header -->
<section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color pi-collapse" data-item-name="itemAttributes">
  <h2 class="pi-item pi-header pi-secondary-font pi-item-spacing pi-secondary-background">Attributes</h2>

  <!--The first column -->

  <section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color" data-item-name="itemAttributeNames">
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability1name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Darkvision</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability2name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Thick Skin</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability3name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Invulnerability</div>
    </div>
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability4name">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Shapeshift</div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--The second column-->

  <section class="pi-item pi-group pi-border-color" data-item-name="itemAttributesDesc">
    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability1">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">The helm allows the wearer to see in dim light.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability2">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Grants immunity to poison.</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability3">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">Grants immunity to wounds. This is a pretty big deal. Like, super over powered. Someone should write to the editor. Or call them. Call right now so we can get some clarification on what the heck is going on here. We need answers. #wtf</div>
    </div>

    <div class="pi-item pi-data pi-item-spacing pi-border-color" data-source="ability4">
      <div class="pi-data-value pi-font">The helm gives the wearer the ability to take any form.</div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

---

Javascript can indeed help, but **it could be wise to rethink the HTML structure**.

I would not advise the `display:content`s method :see support at  https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents

**Here is a tip:** if you can read and understand the content without any style, your document is fine. If every thing is mixed up , that's probably how search engines and other media readers see it.

---

*finally, here is my opinion aside my anwser (you can skip it)*

> *your content seems to deserve a real HTML table. A genuine table for such content is appropriate and there is also ways to make a table responsive if that is a matter.*